# Can you sign messages using Wireguard's keys?

Tags: public-key, authentication, wireguard

I was wondering if I could use Wireguard's keys to sign messages, and prove authenticity of a node that runs Wireguard with its known public key from other nodes, so that I can use it in a system to prove something originated from a certain node and wasn't injected in some other way.

I came across [Encrypt text message with Wireguard public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80325/encrypt-text-message-with-wireguard-public-key) but I didn't really want to encrypt anything, just prove authenticity based on the known public key that other nodes will have.

**Background**: I'm trying to build a federating VPN manager that should allow for building large groups of large virtual networks for use with a container/VM manager, and I'm trying to find an easy way to create node (message) authentication, preferably without building my own complete public/private key infrastructure from scratch; if I would be able to reuse Wireguard's generated keys that would simplify a lot of aspects of my system. But I don't know if this is possible to do in a safe way, or if it's possible at all to begin with.

**Edit:** I just found that I can load Wireguard's Curve25519 key as Ed25519 key with Python's Cryptography libraries, and use that to sign messages ... Whether that's a good idea, I'm very curious to hear others confirm or deny. Here's the Python I used to test it:

```
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519 import Ed25519PrivateKey

# example WireGuard private key I just generated and won't reuse
wireguard_private_key_base64 = '0NyWpZKre0PLTnE0qz/07B5rhZvsQJIm6MS3CxuEHVA='

# Decode the Base64-encoded WireGuard private key
wireguard_private_key_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(wireguard_private_key_base64 + '==')

# 'convert' to Ed25519 private key
try:
    ed25519_private_key = Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(wireguard_private_key_bytes)
    

    message = b"Example message to sign"

    # sign message
    signature = ed25519_private_key.sign(message)

    # printing the signature in base64 so it's more portable/readable
    print("Signature (Base64):", base64.b64encode(signature).decode())

except ValueError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

**Edit2:** I just realized I can't just use the wireguard public key to verify the messages in that case, because Ed25519 derives keys slightly differently (it hashes them first). Someone suggested I could try run a modified Ed25519 without the hashing... but also there not sure if that's a good security practice, and maybe it's also just lower effort if I just derive the Ed25519 public key from the private key right away and send it to the server to store it, or use other pub/private keys to begin with.. unless someone knows a way to make it work.